# Copy files from Azure Blob storage to Azure File Storage with Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-files

I have files in Azure Blob Storage that I want to be able to share with users through an FTP server running on an Azure VM.

As I understand it you can't mount Blob Storage on a VM but you can mount an Azure File Share using 'net use'.

The files on the Blob Storage will be uploaded incrementally so ideally I would like to copy them to Azure files when they are uploaded and Azure Function seems like the ideal way since they are easy to set up and handle the trigger on the Blob Storage for me.

How would I go about copying a file from Blob Storage to an Azure File Share using an Azure function?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a Trigger Binding on the Azure Function to be triggered by Blobs in the Azure Blob Storage Container. Then you'll have to download the file stream of the blob and upload it to the Azure Storage File Share.

Azure Functions do not include support for an Output Binding directly to an Azure Storage File Share. So, you'll need to either use the Azure Storage SDK from in code, or look into mounting the File Share to the Azure Functions runtime environment so you can write file updates to it from within the Azure Function.

An alternative solutions would be to use Azure Logic Apps to implement this without writing any code. This article might help for integrating with an Azure Storage File Share -> [Connect to on-premises file systems form logic apps with the File System connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector)

Comment: Chris .... one minor suggestion .... you don't need to download the blob and upload it in File Share. You can simply use Async Copy Blob functionality and let Azure Storage do the copy from Blob to File Share for you.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, you could use AzCopy to do it for you at command-line, but the question was specifically asking about using Azure Functions and serverless.

Comment: Chris...Disagree with you on this. Async Copy Blob/File is a REST API operation and .NET SDK for Azure Storage exposes that functionality. One could use the SDK in the Azure Function code (which is being used anyways to download the file) and do the copy.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann and Gaurav Mantri, Did you manage to use the Azure Storage SDK in an Azure Function? I get the ERROR:
The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage'
And the ERROR:
The type or namespace name 'CloudStorageAccount' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage'
It seems to me that the function runtime 1 and 2 (preview) doesn't allow to change the target framework and is selecting by default something that doesn't have access to storage. Or I'm just missing something :)